# Show popup after add-to-cart in all browsers

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, woocommerce

I have a WooCommerce webshop where I would like to have a popup appear when people click on "Add to cart".

I have written some code as seen below and it also works as it should. The problem is that it only works in Google Chrome, and not e.g. Safari.

I'm sure the problem is because of the page reloads when you click add to cart in Safari, but how can I fix it?

**header.php**

```
        if (!wp_is_mobile()) {
            echo '<div class="additional-popup">';
            echo '<div class="popup-top">';
                echo '<h3>Added to cart <i class="far fa-check-circle"></i></h3>';
                echo '<div class="additional-btns">';
                    echo '<span class="additional-btn continue">Continue shopping</span>';
                    echo '<a href="" class="additional-btn go-cart">Go to cart</a>';
                echo '</div>';
            echo '</div>';
            echo '<div class="popup-bottom">';
                echo '<h4>Others saw too ...</h4>';
                echo do_shortcode('[products limit="3" columns="3" orderby="rand"]');
            echo '</div>';
        echo '</div>';
        }
```

**additional-sales.js**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $( ".single_add_to_cart_button" ).click(function() {
    $( ".additional-popup" ).addClass( "show" );
    $( "body" ).addClass( "stocked" );
  });

  $( ".continue" ).click(function() {
    $( ".additional-popup" ).removeClass( "show" );
    $( "body" ).removeClass( "stocked" );
  });

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Woocommerce's trigger below to trigger your popup after a product has been added to cart.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('body').on( 'added_to_cart', function(){
        //your popup trigger code here;
    });
});
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply.

I have tried to enter the code below both with and without the click function, but can not make it work ... : - /

`jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('body').on( 'added_to_cart', function(){
        $( ".single_add_to_cart_button" ).click(function() {
    $( ".additional-popup" ).addClass( "show" );
    $( "body" ).addClass( "stocked" );
  });

  $( ".continue" ).click(function() {
    $( ".additional-popup" ).removeClass( "show" );
    $( "body" ).removeClass( "stocked" );
  });
    });
});`

Comment: Can you check Woocommerce > Settings > Products section? Here 'Enable AJAX Add to Cart buttons on archives' must be selected.

Comment: Yes it is. If I click the "Add to cart" button two or more times, it work perfectly. First time the page just reload.

Comment: Where did you inject this javascript? Make sure it is injected into the footer section, not the header

Comment: Your comment made me think of something... I have installed WP Rocket on my website, so when I add "?nowprocket" after my URL, it works as it should. :-D

Now my problem is another... I have otherwise excluded the file from being optimized.

Comment: It's a very small file you can inject it seperately to the footer manually, or you can even add it inline with a widget to your footer.

Comment: I found the error. I had downloaded jQuery twice... After I remove one link, my popup works.

Thank you so much for your help! :-D